# H2 Multiple connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

I have two applications : app1 and app2 , and i want that this two application use the same H2 file as a database .

I test this configuration in the two sides but it didn't work :

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/dBTrunk;MODE=Oracle;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

I am open to all kind of solution my only goal is that app1 and app2 can work in parralel mode with the same H2 database .

Regards

Comment: Could you provide the details for "didn't work" (exception messages,...)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.   The first app should open to the database file in embedded mode, but then start a database server.  The second app will then try to connect to the first app's database server.

If it is not possible for the two apps to talk to each other using TCP/IP, then it wont work.  Is there a firewall between them? Are there certain ports blocked?